# Advanced templating of DataGrid specific to the data in hand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Let's say I have an object that is like:

```
Id = 123456789
Date = 01.01.2013
CurrentItems = 20
TotalItems = 200
A = 25
```

I would like to create a `DataGrid` that is styled similar to the following image:

[image: Sample image of desired style.]

I know how to create a control template for `DataGrid` to change general cell style, but how can I create a template that is specifically for a given data like this?

Comment: google "WPF DataTemplateSelector". after reading through a couple of samples shouldn't take you long to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks useful. What about putting more than one property in one column? Any ideas on that?

Comment: sure, I'll put a code sample for you with a CellDataTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use converters, multi bindings, triggers or template selectors... or a mixture of both

```
<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
              <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myCellTemplateSelector}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

here's multiple bindings on the item of the collection: (I am free typing here, not VS so sorry if there are missed tags etc..)
this one to display 20/200:

```
<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border Background="{Binding MyItems.A}, Converter={StaticResource BlueToRed}">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItems.CurrentItems}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="/"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItems.TotalItems}"/>
           </StackPanel>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```